# How to access /etc/ folder from WSL2 through Ubuntu Terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, shell, wsl2

I wanted to access to `/etc/passwd` from Ubuntu terminal. I don't know where it's located.

I have tried the following:

```
cd /mnt/c/Users/<my_username>/AppData/Local/Packages/CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc
```

But I wasn't able to spot the `/etc/` folder anywhere inside this location.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SuperUser! Did you already try `cd /etc`?

Comment: Access? How?  `/etc/passwd` is the full path to the `passwd` file... Did you try the command `cat /etc/passwd` ?

Comment: Oh yes cat works

Comment: Yes, `cat` works because the Linux filesystem structure exists at root (or `/`), whereas `/mnt/c/` is where your Windows C-drive is mounted.

Comment: But the real question is why are you trying access `passwd` file? It rarely contains useful information and shouldn't be edited directly.

Comment: This is unlikely to end up as a good Q&A combination, I suggest to close it.